# Problema con Ionic

Tags: ionic, windows10

Hola Tengo un Problema al Crear un Proyecto de Ionic (Primera Vez que Lo Utilizo)
Me Sale Lo Siguiente:

ionic : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\win 10 pro\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1 porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada
en este sistema. Para obtener más información, consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- ionic serve
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que lo estas ejecutando con la consola powershell, para arreglarlo es lo siguiente:

1. Busca una consola de powershell, click secundario `ejecutar como administrador`.
2. Una vez en la consola agregas el comando `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` , te deberia quedar así:

   `C:\Users\user>Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

y con eso podras ejecutar scripts en tu consola powershell sin problemas.

- Si deseas volver a desactivar la ejecucion de scripts usa el comando `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted`

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono, ¿Hay alguna forma de definir un directorio en especifico?